# How to Implement Anti CSRF for ASP.net Web forms (not for asp.net MVC)

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, webforms, csrf

How to implement Anti CSRF for whole website for ASP.net web forms.
Is there any way to implement it in our Global.asax file or web.config file for all the request and response.

we are using .net 3.5 and VS-2012 and we don't have any master page.

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with similar challenge. Bottom line is you really can't.
Initially I try to make VIEWSTATE secure from web.config, but this is not good enough. You need to make VIEWSTATE Key **unique** in each session.

So you either need master page, or some kind of page or code being triggered  for each user session. And this scenario(each user session)  is not covered by either web.config or app.config.

Hope this clarifies and I know this is disappointing too...

Luckily my project(with 400+ forms) is using master page, so I was able to implement it.

I'm sure you've seen this implementation, but just in case.
http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf